# Disconnecting a browser tab (testing what happens when the user connection breaks)

Tags: macos, user-interface, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm looking for a way to force a connection break (a way to disconnect) a browser tab.

What I'm trying to do is to test my site, where I open a websocket to the server from the browser, and then emulate a disconnection, but just on that browser tab (or even just on the browser), because I need my connection to check what happens on the server in that precise instant.

I was looking for a chrome extension to do so, but I don't find any. But any way to accomplish that would be fine.

My client OS is MacOSX 10.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome now there's an "offline" option, under the Network tab from the DevTools, but if you are looking for a websocket disconnection, like myself, you must be aware of this:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423246

Answer (score 0):

You could just kill the browser process. In that case the browser wouldn't be able to close the connection gracefully. It would pretty much look like a severed network connection to the server.

See [this question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/192219/list-and-kill-running-processes-on-mac-os-in-ctrl-alt-delete-like-way) for how to kill a process on MacOS.

An even more realistic test would be to set up a virtual machine, run the client there (or the server), and then interrupt the virtual network connection.

Another option would be to set up a local proxy server (note that few proxy servers already support WebSockets), connect to the server through this proxy, and then simulate an interrupted connection by killing the proxy. That way you could observer both the servers and the clients reaction to the event.

Comment: I need to keep the client open, to see how the client side part of the application behaves.

The virtual machine would be a solution, but I think it is overkill, since this is something I must test frequently, and opening a virtual machine just for that would be a bit of a waste of time and machine resources.

Comment: When you want to test the clients behavior, then why not kill the server process? Another alternative would be to run the connection between client and server through a local proxy server and then kill the proxy process.

Comment: I need to see how both behave on the connection breaking, but also how they recover when the connection is back on, so killing is not an option :-)

About the proxy, it seems like a good idea, but I want the simulation to be as realistic as possible.

What I'm doing right know is connecting the client on another machine, and unplug the network cable. It works, but I want something faster and more efficient.

Comment: the most realistic test would be the variant with the virtual machine, right after what you are already doing. As a web developer you should know how to use virtual machines anyway, because it's the least expensive way to test if your website renders properly on different operating systems.

Comment: Well, the fact is I know how to use them, just cannot have virtualbox open all day on my dev machine (resources) and I cannot spend my time opening and closing it for every test.

Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, use `Menu | Tools | Task Manager` to see a list of tabs. You can kill a tab in the middle of a page load from there.

Comment: But I need to keep the tab open to see also what happens on the client side.